# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule

Tags: php, urls, regex

Struggling to get this working, i've never used regex before or played with .htaccess so i'm struggling to get this work.

Eventually what i want to try and achieve is:

mywebsite/vehicle-info/bmw/s6/petrol/variant1

That url to transform to

mywebsite/vehicle-info?model=bmw&make=s6&fuel=petrol&variant=variant1

I am currently trying to just get it work with just 1 parameter. What i currently have is:

```
function add_query_vars($new_var) {
$new_var[] = "vehicle-info";
return $new_var;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array('([^/]+)' => 'vehicle-info?&model=$matches[1]');
    $rules = $new_rules + $rules;
   return $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Currently with the code above i am trying to achieve

mywebsite/vehicle-info/bmw

to transform to

mywebsite/vehicle-info?make=bmw

Any help please?

Cheers.

Comment: Try the following: `$new_rules = array('([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)' => 'vehicle-info?model=$matches[1]&make=$matches[2]&fuel=$matches[3]&variant=$matches[4]');`

Comment: Just tried it but it just redirects me to the homepage. Cheers.

Comment: is `mywebsite/vehicle-info` the home page of the website ? try also this function : https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: the home page is mywebsite, the/vehicle-info is a different page. I'll take a look now thank you

Comment: What is vehicle-info? A WordPress page? make, fuel, variant need to be added as query vars. I suggest looking at the examples on the add_rewrite_rule codex page, note how all internal rules point to index.php.